# Program hangs upwards of 60 seconds in between the __init__ and the run method starting?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've encountered an odd problem. <del>As best as I can tell, the actual act of assigning data to a variable is causing a massive delay in my program. I measured the time it takes to actually build the data that I want to assign to an instance variable, and it averages right around .7 seconds. It is only when I try to assign it (e.g. `self.data = data`) that the massive delay happens.</del>

### EDIT:

The above assumption was incorrect. It was *not* hanging during the variable assignment. I added a timer before and after the call to `build_data` and the time is negligible.

The delay is somehow in between when `__init__` finishes and `run` is called.

#### Updated Class

Here is the code for the class. I added a timer which starts at the end of `__init__` and stops at the first call to `run()`. There is a 50 second delay between the two!

```
class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue, image): 
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.data = self.build_data(image)
            self.start_time = time.time()

    def run(self): 
        print 'I finally reached the run statement!'
        print "Time taken:", time.time() - self.start_time
        print "Exiting {}".format(self.name)
```

And the `build_data` function.

```
        def build_data(self, im): 
            start_time = time.time()
            size, data = im.size, list(im.getdata())
            data = [data[x:size[0] + x] for x in range(0, len(data), size[0])]
            print 'Process time:', time.time() - start_time
            return data
```

Any one know what could be causing this?

#### Worker pool code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    workers = [] 
    for i in range(1): 
        w = Worker(queue, im)
        w.start()
        workers.append(w)


    print 'waiting for workers to join'
    for i in workers: i.join()
```

### Partial Solution:

At Toreks suggestion, I looked through the programming guidelines on `multiprocessing`, which states that all arguments passed to `__init__` are picklable. My understanding on the internals are very fuzzy, but I guess that delay in the code was the giant nested list structure being pickled/unpickled as it was passed to `__init__` (Could be completely wrong on that fact though).

Moving the data out of `__init__`, and assigning it later cleared up the problem completely. No more delay.

#### Working code:

```
class Worker(DataStore):
    data = None
    def __init__(self, queue, image): 
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.img = image
        self.start_time = time.time() 


    def run(self):
        self.assign_data(self.img)
        print 'I finally reached the run statement!'
        print "Time taken:", time.time() - self.start_time
        print "Exiting {}".format(self.name)


    @classmethod
    def assign_data(cls, im): 
        size, data = im.size, list(im.getdata())
        cls.data = [
            data[x:size[0] + x] for x in range(0, len(data), size[0])
        ]
```

So, I just moved the `data`variable to the class scope, and then turned `build_data` into a `@classmethod`. All works swimmingly now.

Comment: How many Workers are you running?

Comment: @DavidRobinson just the one. I'll edit the post with the worker start up code.

Comment: Is this on Windows or a Unix-ish system?  The `.start()` method has to invoke the bootstrapper; on Unix-ish systems this is pretty easy, and on Windows it's ugly; see [programming guidelines](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming) in the docs.

Comment: @torek Windows machine. Weirdly, I'm guessing this is related to the first item in the Windows guidelines: `Ensure that all arguments to Process.__init__() are picklable.` I moved the data variable out of `__init__` and just like that, everything runs fine. No more delay. Is **all** data pickled in `__init__` regardless of where it was generated from (in this a case, a method in the same class)? Can anyone explain the details of what exactly is going on in `__init__`? Either way, works now! So, thanks @torek!

Comment: On Windows it uses (a slightly hacked) `pickle.dump` to write the process-object-instance, which in this case would be the `Worker` instance.  You can see what's involved by calling `pickle.dump` on an instance (after creating but before `start`ing), writing that to a temp file, and then examining the temp file contents.

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro Maybe you can answer your own question, and accept it? This would be very valuable for others that would face the same problem.